# PHP Unit test database queries on XAMPP

Tags: php, unit-testing, xampp

Want to unit test connection with database, if it retrieves hardcoded test users.

What I have is Test class "DatabaseQueryHandlerTest"

```
<?php
    use \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
    require_once 'DatabaseQueryHandler.php';

    class DatabaseQueryHandlerTest extends TestCase
    {      
        public function testShouldFindAdminDataRow()
        {  
            require("dbconnection.php");
            $databaseHandler = new DatabaseQueryHandler();
            $result = $databaseHandler->SelectFromAdmin("UnitTestAdmin", "UnitTestPswAdm");
            $this->assertEquals(true, $result != null);
        }
    }
?>
```

Then I have "DatabaseQueryHandler" itself.

```
<?php  
    require_once("User.php");
       
    class DatabaseQueryHandler
    {
        public function SelectFromAdmin($username, $password )
        {
            require_once("dbconnection.php");
            $ret=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE name='{$username}' and password='{$password}'");
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret);

            if($row >0)
            {
                $user = new User();
                $user->SetId($row['id']);
                $user->SetName($row['name']);
                return $user;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
?>
```

And finally my "dbconnection" file.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crm");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Connection Fail".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

After running command `"./vendor/bin/phpunit"` I get errors from Unit Tests.

```
Time: 00:00.081, Memory: 4.00 MB
 
There were 2 errors:
 
1) DatabaseQueryHandlerTest::testShouldFindAdminDataRow
Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
 
C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\dbconnection.php:2
C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\tests\DatabaseQueryHandlerTest.php:9
 
2) DatabaseQueryHandlerTest::testShouldFindAdminDataRow
Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
 
C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\dbconnection.php:2
C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\tests\DatabaseQueryHandlerTest.php:9
 
ERRORS!
Tests: 15, Assertions: 13, Errors: 2.
```

And can't seem to be able to fix these tests. Need some help.

Comment: Do not add pictures of code. Please add one or more code block(s) with all relevant code.

Comment: Updated as per comments.